# Can anyone, as a non-Jew, ask Jews to pray for them?

Tags: tefilla, gentiles

Can anyone, as a non-Jew, ask Jews to pray for them? Just the normal things (not to lose against evil, for a healthy and happy life, that sort of thing). Under what situations would a Jew be permitted to pray for a non-Jew, if they were asked sincerely etc.?

To be more specific: agnostics who nevetheless believe in the power of prayer, if only because of the next life.

Comment: Ha, I don't mean doing so forcefully, just "please say a prayer for me :-) "  ?

Comment: Regarding praying for a Non-Jew: in Halachically Speaking, the Chukei Hachai is cited (Chukei Hachai, Parashas Va’eira, page 45) saying: Some want to say that praying for a non-Jew with intentions to save the entire Jewish nation is permitted, but in a regular situation praying for a non-Jew would not be allowed. Even Avraham Avinu prayed for the people of Sedom (Bereishis Rabbah 39:6).

Comment: OK interesting thanks! This is quite a convoluted and awful existential moment for me @Shmuel so your honesty is appreciated

Comment: Maybe remedy the phrasing of your question. There almost certainly isn't any issue simply asking a Jew to pray for you, but there are some halachic considerations for the Jew on whether he's allowed to actually go through with it :)

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know enough about Judaism to make a better question @RabbiKaii

Comment: @vqlk from your above comment, perhaps it sounds like you need to speak to someone directly, as this is not a personal issues forum. Happy if you wish to start up a chat, no guarantees I can be if any use

Comment: I would recommend rephrasing your question to be more general. There's a chance this question will be closed because it's asking for a personal advice (halachic, jewish law advice).

Comment: However, there are different sources that explain otherwise. Moses prayed for non-jews, Avraham prayed for non-jews. see: https://thehalacha.com/wp-content/uploads/Vol17Issue1.pdf I do want to stress out what Rabbi Kaii mentions. Sometimes, it is good to go beyond the letter of the law, especially when seeing a person in distress.

Comment: OK I might do that @RabbiKaii there is, I think, no rush. Cheers

Comment: I just want to add one last thing. Following halacha is always the best thing you can do towards making your situation better.

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140080/jews-praying-for-gentiles @RabbiKaii thanks for any help, and no worries if you don't say anything :) !

Comment: Avraham didn't exactly pray for (all) the people of Sedom, he only demanded proper justice that the righteous not be destroyed with the wicked.  However R' Elazar said he could have done better אמר רבי אלעזר, אוף אברהם לא עבד שלימו כדקא יאות, https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/109580/why-didnt-abraham-ask-the-single-best-question

Comment: @RabbiKaii i hope you are pleased to be told, and i think it the case, that i "won", and all else that matters here is whether "God" smiles on me when judging how I should be when i die. Thanks :)

Comment: @tiptoe I am happy things worked out for you, whatever they were :)

Comment: ah schizophrenia is crazy @RabbiKaii i am not historically significant, and it was an internal thing i.e. not worth explaining. thanks for any blessings at all

Comment: everyone is infinitely significant and needed on earth